# Studying convergence of $\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n}$ for $a,n \in \mathbb{R^+}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

There is two cases $a = 0 $ and $ a \ne 0  $. This was my attempt. Case $a = 0$:

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n} + \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n}$$

But $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x^n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}$$ converges for $n<2$ and diverges for $n\ge2$. And

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{-1}{x^n}< \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n} < \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^n}$$  converges for $n>1$ and diverges for $n\le1$. That means that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n}$ converges for $n \in]1,2[$ and diverges for $n \in \mathbb{R}- ]1,2[$.

How would we be able to study the convergence?

Comment: Which integral are you using? Riemann / Darboux?

Comment: i'm using Riemann

Comment: Do you know Dirichlet's criterion.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima no

Comment: @edcharlie stack it {}{}{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make "$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{-1}{x^n}$< $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n}$ < $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^n}$  converges for $n>1$ and diverges for $n\leq1$".

We divide $[\pi,+\infty)$ into $[k\pi,k\pi+\pi),k\in N$. Thus,
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{2}{(k+1)^\alpha\pi^\alpha}\leq\int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}dx\leq\frac{2}{k^\alpha\pi^\alpha},\ &&x\in[k\pi,k\pi+\pi),\quad k\ \text{is even，}\\
\frac{-2}{k^\alpha\pi^\alpha}\leq\int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}dx\leq\frac{-2}{(k+1)^\alpha\pi^\alpha},\ &&x\in[k\pi,k\pi+\pi),\quad k\ \text{is odd.}
\end{eqnarray}

By **Leibniz's test**, this integral converges anyway when $\alpha>0$, but does not absolutely converges when $\alpha\leq1$.

Comment: is $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x^n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}$$ converges for $n<2$ and diverges for $n\ge2$. correct ?

Comment: @edcharlie This one is correct, but I suggest you not write "=" directly. You can denote the relationship by "~". That is , $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x^n}dx\sim\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^n}dx$.